# How to make a graph with a 'list' class variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a completely new user to R and general statistics.
Right now I'm trying to make a dotplot by using `ggplot2`
but the problem is, the data that I downloaded has the variable that I want to use as x-axis as a 'list' class(e.g. c(110, 43).

To be specific, I want to make a dotplot for the landing locations from a soccer corner.
Basically, `c(120,1)` is where the corner is taken, and `c(110,43)` is where the cross landed.
So I want to make a dotplot of all the landing spots of a corner, and if the number 110 and 43 were separated, I could just put 110 in the x-axis and 43 in the y, but since they're grouped together in one variable, I'm confused as to whether it is possible to make a graph in this situation.

```
index period    timestamp      duration location 

446   446      1 00:13:41.347    1.960  120, 79
447   447      1 00:13:43.307       NA  110, 39
448   448      1 00:13:43.307       NA   10, 41
449   449      1 00:13:43.307    1.973  111, 42
450   450      1 00:13:45.280       NA    2, 40
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this... I would follow up with any confusions

Comment: Please add sample data and code used to make an attempt.

Comment: Use `dput(head(df,10))` to add sample data to the question. Click "edit" to edit the question.

Comment: sorry took me some time to organize the sample data, and I did learn some very basic visualization through online videos, but ggplot(data, aes(location)) + geom_dotpolot() gave me a blank plot

Comment: It's easier to help if you provide data as I've suggested above.